# insert to database in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing an insert into a database in php so that it submits more than one row as the information to be submitted is dynamically generated.problem is that it only submits the last data and ignores the rest.how do i do it?here is my code:

```
<?php
include('includes/conn.php');
$row="SELECT name,refNo,department FROM profile WHERE     department='$getid'";
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$row)  or die(mysqli_error($conn));
echo "<div class='col-md-4 col-md-offset-1' >";
echo "<table class='table table-hover table-striped table-bordered'>
<tr class='info'>
</tr>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $name=$row['name'];
    $job=$row['refNo'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['refNo']."</td>";
    echo "<form method='post' action='selection.php'>";
    echo "<td>"."<input type='text' name='essential' class='form-control' width='100%' required>"."</td>";
    echo "<td>"."<input type='text' name='desirable' class='form-control' width='100%' required>"."</td>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='name' value='".$name."'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='job' value='".$job."'>";
    echo "</tr>";
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $job=$_POST['job'];
        $essential=$_POST['essential'];
        $desirable=$_POST['desirable'];
        $insert="INSERT INTO shortlist(name,job,points) VALUES('$name','$job','$essential' + '$desirable')";
        $query=mysqli_query($conn,$insert) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        if($query)
        {
            header("location:index.php");
        }
    }
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' name='submit' value='Submit'>";
"</form>";
echo "</div>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Why are you inserting inside the while loop?

Comment: If your query is true, it will go to index.php and will not be able to continue the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You should insert outside the while loop with one statement only. Try this one.

```
$query = mysqli_query ( $conn, $row ) or die ( mysqli_error ( $conn ) );
echo "<div class='col-md-4 col-md-offset-1' >";
echo "<table class='table table-hover table-striped table-bordered'>

<tr class='info'>

</tr>";
//insert outside while loop
$insert = "INSERT INTO shortlist(name,job,points) VALUES ";
$values = array();
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $query ) ) {
    $name = $row ['name'];
    $job = $row ['refNo'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row ['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row ['refNo'] . "</td>";
    echo "<form method='post' action='selection.php'>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='essential' class='form-control' width='100%' required>" . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='desirable' class='form-control' width='100%' required>" . "</td>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='name' value='" . $name . "'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='job' value='" . $job . "'>";
    echo "</tr>";
    if (isset ( $_POST ['submit'] )) {
        $name = $_POST ['name'];
        $job = $_POST ['job'];
        $essential = $_POST ['essential'];
        $desirable = $_POST ['desirable'];
        //fetch values
        $values[] = "('" . $name . "','" . $job . "','" . ($essential + $desirable) . "')";
        if ($query) {
            header ( "location:index.php" );
        }
    }
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' name='submit' value='Submit'>";
"</form>";

echo "</div>";
// implode and append all the values, will generate a sql like 'insert into table_name (column_group) values (val_group_1),(val_group_2)'
$insert .= implode(',',$values); 
//insert multiple rows at one time
$query = mysqli_query ( $conn, $insert ) or die ( mysqli_error ( $conn ) );
mysqli_close ( $conn );
?>
```

Comment: I am getting this error :" You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

Comment: Can you echo the $query variable before executing to see what it is?

Comment: I would suggest this solution combined with that of @AnkitArjaria. But it needs a check that the $values array has 1 or more entries and if not to bypass performing the query. Also make the field values safe by escaping them.

Answer (score 1):

You are using simple name not array in your form input
Your generated form looks like

```
<form method='post' action='selection.php'>
<input type='text' name='essential' >
<input type='text' name='desirable' >
</form>
```

So only last value is saved in the form input
You should use array of names in input form like That

```
<form method='post' action='selection.php'>
<input type='text' name='essential[]' >
<input type='text' name='desirable[]' >
</form>
```

in this way all values will be saved in name array like
i am showing essential array output

// printed output

Array
(

```
[0] => First input value

[1] => Second input value

[2] => Third input value
```

)
you can print whole posted array by 
print_r() function this will help you more in storing multiple record

Answer (score 0):

You are try to seperate two value of column using + . It is use as

```
  $essential=$_POST['essential'];
  $desirable=$_POST['desirable'];
  $val=$essential+$desirable;
  $insert="INSERT INTO shortlist(`name`,`job`,`points`) VALUES('".$name."','".$job."','".$val."')";
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem of OP.

Answer (score 0):

#### Note:

- If you want to pursue the logic you want with your code, you can just remove the `if(!$query)` condition. If your query is true, it will go to index.php and will not be able to continue the loop. So only the first data will be inserted.
- If you still want the user to be redirect to index.php after the insert query, you can try this:

Code:

```
...END OF YOUR INSERT AND WHILE LOOP HERE...

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  header("LOCATION:index.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Merging the replies from @EasonLuo and @AnkitArjaria, putting the fields out as arrays and doing a single insert after looping through the input:-

```
<?php
include('includes/conn.php');
echo "<div class='col-md-4 col-md-offset-1' >";
echo "<form method='post' action='selection.php'>";
echo "<table class='table table-hover table-striped table-bordered'>
<tr class='info'>
</tr>";
$values = array();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    foreach($_POST['name'] AS $key=>$value)
    {
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name'][$key]);
        $job = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['job'][$key]);
        $essential = (int)$_POST['essential'][$key];
        $desirable =(int)$_POST['desirable'][$key];
        $values[] = "('$name','$job',".($essential + $desirable).")";
    }
    if (count($values) > 0)
    {
        $insert = "INSERT INTO shortlist(name,job,points) VALUES ".implode(', ', $values);
        $query = mysqli_query($conn,$insert) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        if($query)
        {
            header("location:index.php");
        }
    }
}

$row = "SELECT name,refNo,department FROM profile WHERE department='$getid'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$row)  or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$cnt = 0;

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $cnt++;
    $name = $row['name'];
    $job = $row['refNo'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['refNo']."</td>";
    echo "<td>"."<input type='text' name='essential[$cnt]' class='form-control' width='100%' required>"."</td>";
    echo "<td>"."<input type='text' name='desirable[$cnt]' class='form-control' width='100%' required>"."</td>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='name[$cnt]' value='".$name."'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='job[$cnt]' value='".$job."'>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' name='submit' value='Submit'>";
"</form>";
echo "</div>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```